# Ionic: How to add params to html [navPush]?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

In a JS file I would write

```
navPush(page, {paramOne: "something"})
```

In html, in order to write a push, I'd write

```
[navPush]="modelPage"
```

How do I add params to the above, in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters using the navParams property along with your navPush.
It's use is mentioned in ionic [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/NavPush/). you can use it in your html as:

```
<button ion-button [navPush]="pushPage" [navParams]="params">Go</button> // params is the object which you intend to pass to the page;
```

Comment: Does it just take a string, or do I need can I write key-value pairs? Also, I'm getting a parsing error when trying to make this dynamic using [navParams]="{{model.id}}"

Comment: you can pass the dynamic property like this: [navParams]="{data:model.id}" and access in the same way in the pushed page with the navParams.get('data')

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically bind a single value you can use this code

```
<button ion-button [navPush]="NextPage" [navParams]="{color:[color]}">GO</button> // where color is a string variable
```

On NextPage use this code

```
this.color = navParams.get('color');
console.log(this.color[0]);
```